# How to load prompt values from Excel or CSV files in WebI?

Tags: excel, csv, business-objects

We have report and users want to upload filters to prompts on the reports from Excel or CSV files. They cannot enter one by one because they sometimes have hundreds of values (customer numbers) to filter. Is there a way to do that? If it is then how is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Niki

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using either Web Intelligence or a different document format that is supported by the OpenDocument feature.

One possibility is to use an Excel file with a column for each prompt value. Use this Excel file as a source for a new Web Intelligence document. Within that document, construct OpenDocument URLs that contains the prompt values you want to pass.

Make sure that you read the OpenDocument manual carefully, as the syntax for passing prompt values differs depending on how the prompt is configured (single value vs. multiple values, etc).

The idea behind this is that you have an easy to maintain Excel file to input/modify the prompt values, and that end-users can open the intermediate Web Intelligence document, refresh it (or use refresh on open) and then click one of the generated links to automatically open the correct document and have all the prompt values filled in.

## Example

Consider the screenshot below. It's an Excel file that contains information regarding two documents (*Dummy Report* and *Other Report*) as well as their internal ID (CUID) and the prompt values to refresh them with.

[image: Spreadsheet]

This is sufficient information to generate an OpenDocument URL to open these documents for us and automatically enter the prompt values.

The resulting URLs would look like this:

```
http://<servername>:<port>/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=Aa6GrrM79cRAmaOSMGoadKI&sIDType=CUID&lsSYear=2015&lsSMonth=2

http://<servername>:<port>/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?iDocID=Aa6GrrM79cRAmaOSMGoadKI&sIDType=CUID&lsSYear=2015&lsSMonth=2&lsSCity=Berlin
```

Some remarks here:

- If your documents have different prompts (e.g. *City* is a prompt in the second document but not in the first), or some of the prompts are optional, you'll have to check for which columns (prompts) a value has been provided in the Excel sheet and discard the empty ones (should be easy enough).
- Unless Single Sign-On (SSO) has been configured in your BusinessObjects environment, you'll still have to log on.
- Due to this approach, you can make prompt values dynamic (e.g. use the current year) by using Excel formulas.
- The example above is a very simple one. You could have multiple lines referring to the same document but with different prompt values.

#### Taking it one step further

If you use this Excel sheet as a data source for a Web Intelligence document, you can create a Webi document that contains the OpenDocument links. The added bonus is that you won't have to log on anymore after clicking one of the links, as you're already working in an authenticated session.

## Important

Make sure you read the OpenDocument manual carefully so you understand what it is and how it can be used (and more importantly, what you *can't* do with it). You can find the manual on [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com/bobip?current=pcat_analytics&show_children=false#section7). Just make sure the version described in the manual corresponds with the version of BusinessObjects deployed in your environment.

Comment: I could not get you completely. OpenDocument URLs means? Can you please help me in understanding.

Comment: @ Kristof - I could understand about the Opendocument URL .But could you please help me understand how to bring that values to the prompt?

Comment: The prompt values can be passed as part of the URL. That's why you create the URL by concatenating the values as shown in the example.

Comment: @ Kristof : When you pass the prompt value IsSYear=2015 in the URL, we get the output only for 2015? how to get for many values? Apologies if i confused.

Answer (score 2):

Not currently possible.  What we did for this requirement was to create a new dedicated table in our database to hold customer-generated prompt values.  We then created a simple web page to allow users to upload lists of values.  Finally, we created universe objects that associate the customers' LOV table with existing universe objects as filters.

Comment: thanks Joe. Can you please explain little bit more elaborately from the part of creating web page like how and how it is taken to universe?